# Providing context for @Value fields from a unit test

Tags: java, spring

I have a class like this:

```
@Service("someClient")
public class SomeClient {

  @Value{some.value}
  private String someValue;

  public void someMethod() {
    return someValue;
  }

}
```

And a test like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/some/where/testApplicationContext.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SomeClientTest extends TestCase {

  @Value{some.value}
  private String someValueTest;

  @Test
  public void shouldWork() {
    ...
    someClient.someMethod()
    ...        
  }

}
```

When the wider application is running, the field someValue inside the SomeClient class is populated from a properties file referenced from testApplicationContext.xml. When I run the test in debug mode I can see that someValueTest is populated in the test, but when the test calls the class under test, the value is not populated.

I could use some advice! Obviously I can change the visibility of the field in the class, or provide a setter, however I would like to avoid that if possible. If it isn't, please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to populate fields with @Value annotation in your test you need to configure `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Add the following to your test:

```
    @Configuration
    public static class Config {
    @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer() {
            return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        }
    }
```

To read the values from test property file you can add 
`@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")` to your Test class declaration

Comment: So my issue isn't populating the field in the test, but the class under test when called from the test. So to be clear, the property correctly populates in the test. It correctly populates when the application is run normally. However, when the class is called from the test it does not populate.

Comment: How do you instantiate the class under the test?

Comment: as a field on the test:

  private SomeClient client = new SomeClient();

Comment: Then it is not managed by Spring. You need to set value manually. If you want the value set, it has to be configured as a bean

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution and replies jny!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ReflectionTestUtils** from **org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils** package to mock any variable, including the ones that access the properties file.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SomeClientTest extends TestCase {

  private SomeClient someClient;

  @Test
  public void shouldWork() {
    //Initialize someClient
    someClient = new SomeClient();
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(someClient, "variable name", "the variable value");
    someClient.someMethod()
    ...        
  }

}
```