# When running test class, properties can't be read properly from .properties file by using @Value annotation, in Spring Maven project

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc

//Update

After viewing helpful comments, I realize the problem should then be, how to unit test method using values read from properties by @Value .

//

I am working on this issue for days, I am writing unit test for a serviceClass.The serviceClass is like below :

```
import ...
@Component
public class ServiceClass implements ServiceInterface {
    @Value("${data.layer.url}")
    private String  dataLayerUrl;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate

    public void dummy(){
        restTemplate.postForObject(dataLayerUrl + "/" + ... , ...);
    }

}
```

And CONFIG_DIR is already defined in application configuration file.

I have a SomeConfig class defining beans as below. (...src/main/java/com.app/configuration/SomeConfig)

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"..."})
@PropertySource(value = "file:${CONFIG_DIR}/app.properties")
public class SomeConfig{

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            ...
            return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

My test class is as below:

```
Import ...
@Profile("test")
public class ServiceClassTest extends AbstractTest {
     @Value("${data.layer.url}")
     private String  dataLayerUrl;

     @InjectMocks
     private ServiceClass ServiceClass;
     @Mock
     RestTemplate restTemplate;
     @Before
     public void initializeMockito() {
         MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
     }    
     @Test
     public void dummyTest(){
         when(restTemplate.postForObject(dataLayerUrl + "/" + ..., ...)).thenReturn(...);
         serviceClass.dummy();

         assertEquals(...);
         verify(restTemplate).postForObject(...);
     }
}
```

And then my AbstractTest as below :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = ...)
public abstract class AbstractTest {
    protected Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
}
```

And I also have .../src/test/resources/application-test.properties defined as below

```
#Datalayer properties
data.layer.url=http://camel-dev-01.xxx.com:5001
```

This is the same as defined in application.properties(which locates outside of project in CONFIG_DIR.

The logic of testing is just to make sure when you call dummy method of serviceClass, the postForObject method of restTemplate is called exactly once.

But when doing it this way, I am facing with 2 problems.
when I run test class in debug mode, I found

1. in ServiceClassTest. dataLayerUrl = "$data.layer.url"
2. in ServiceClass.     dataLayerUrl = null

I researched around and be able to solve problem one by following this link
https://gist.github.com/danlangford/3418696

But this is not an ideal way to do this, since by default spring should be able to read properties from application-test.properties.
And I never figured out what caused the second issue and how to solve it.

I think this would be a common issue when writing unit test on class which read properties from .properties file using $Value annotation. Any comments or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `@Value` only works on spring beans, you are using Mockito to create a mock of a class. That instance isn't a spring managed bean so your `@Value` is pretty much useless.

Comment: then what would be a proper way to read properties which would work well with Mockito test? Any way for the mocked ServiceClass to read its properties ?

Comment: No because it isn't a spring managed bean. The `@Value` will only work on spring managed beans (your test isn't one either). You are using mocks, if you want to use spring values use spring managed instances.

Comment: The question would then be, how to unit test method from such a ServiceClass, if there is no way to get properties from properties file. But those properties values are needed in the method to be tested? I am new to spring and Junit test. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The key point hear as said M. Deinum is that you use a mix of Spring bean and Mock Object that in this case aren't Spring bean and for this reason can't benefit of the feature of Spring Container such as the injection of the properties.

In particular you should use the spring test abstraction as a "integration test" istruments. With this words I intended that you should use this abstraction, for test the correct configuration, behavior and so on fo your bean in the spring contex. However if you use Stub or mock object you actually exit, of a smal part probably, by the management of spring and the your test don't make sense. Using stub or mock the your test become a Unit test in sense that it will be a test the your bean and functionality in isolation infact you have mock or stub the dependency of your object.

I hope that this reflection could be help you

Comment: So you mean there is no way and no need to unit test on this ? And we should test inside container instead?

Comment: let say rhat @value is a spring feature then if you want test also that your configuration of propertiesconfiguration woks fine you want an integration test because you want test the correct integratikn of one or mor spring featuref in your aplicatioj

Comment: i'm sorry for the wrong word.... i written it with my tablet, i just repeate the comment for a better reading:  
let say that @value is a spring feature, then if you want test also that your configuration properties woks fine, you want an integration test because you want test the correct integration of one or more spring feature in your aplication

Answer (score 0):

I am glad to know there is no way to read values from properties by @Value inside a mock obj.

But still my problem is that I want to unit test my dummy method in ServiceClass. Put it another way, as long as I could unit test this method, I don't care whether @Value works or not.

Here is my solution of test method

```
@Profile("test")
public class ServiceClassTest extends AbstractTest {
     @Value("${data.layer.url}")
     private String  dataLayerUrl;

     @InjectMocks
     private ServiceClass ServiceClass;
     @Mock
     RestTemplate restTemplate;
     @Before
     public void initializeMockito() {
         MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
     }    
     @Test
     public void dummyTest(){
         when(restTemplate.postForObject(anyString() , eq(), eq() )).thenReturn(...);
         serviceClass.dummy();

         assertEquals(...);
         verify(restTemplate).postForObject(anyString(), eq(), eq());
     }
```

By using anyString, I don't rely on what value is read from properties, since I only want to test whether dummy method call restTemplate's postForObject method properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to your test configuration in order to populate properties annotated with `@Value` annotation. Spring Boot adds it to configuration, but since your test is running without Spring Boot you have to declare it. For more details see[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35229426/562721) .

Answer (score 0):

in place of @InjectMocks you can write @Autowired and I thing you can use both annotation like that

Case 1

```
 @InjectMocks
 private ServiceClass ServiceClass;
```

case 2

```
@Autowired 
 @InjectMocks
 private ServiceClass ServiceClass;
```

I have same issue but after discussion my senior I have find above like solutions